# I need to link two new entries via suite CRM API

Tags: php, web-services, relationship, suitecrm

I used the module builder to create two custom modules (`File`, `Operation`). Then i create a relationship between them (one to many, File -> Operation) inside Studio. I use the `Suite CRM API (v4.1)` to set entry to File module and Operation Module and works. Now I want to link these new entries, but the set_relationship method doesn't work. Any help?

```php
$entryArgs = array(
            'session' => $sessId,
            'module_name' => 'sm111_File',
            'name_value_list' => array(
                    array('name' => 'name','value' => $file_id),
                    array('name' => 'arithmosf_c', 'value' => $number),
                ),
            );
$file_result = restRequest('set_entry',$entryArgs);
$file_ID = $file_result['id'];

$operationEntry = array(
            'session' => $sessId,
            'module_name' => 'med11_Operation',
            'name_value_list' => array(
                    array('name' => 'name','value' => $operation_name),
                ),
            );
$operation_result = restRequest('set_entry',$operationEntry);
$operation_ID = $operation_result['id'];

$set_relationship_parameters = array('session' => $sessId,
    'module_name' => 'sm111_File',
    'module_id' => $file_ID,
    'link_field_name' => 'med11_Operation',
    'related_ids' => $operation_ID,
    'name_value_list' => array(),
    'delete'=> 0,
);

print_r(restRequest('set_relationship',$set_relationship_parameters));
```

The result is this.

```
Array ( 
  [created] => 0 
  [failed]  => 1 
  [deleted] => 0 
)
```

Comment: This code works fine with Account and Contacts, so the problem is about custom modules relationship.